# AngularJS : Passing data to remote controller from ui-router state & url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**SOLVED: See below**

**I have the following illustration with actual [PLUNKER CODER HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/BhXNY9bKMpiOjA8RlZen?p=preview)**

[image]

**I have been successful in dynamically changing the left menu to 1 of 2 possibilities and well as the respective view but my code is crude and I noticed this will NOT work if I upgrade to UI-Router 0.2.1.**

**1. The gist of my left menu code:**

```
<a data-ng-click="stateGo({state: viewState.Name}, {moduleId : viewState.Url})" style="cursor:pointer;">{{ viewState.Name}}</a>
```

**2. The controller:**

```
angular.module("app")
.controller("LeftPanelCtrl", [
    '$location', '$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function ($location, $scope, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
        $scope.pageTitle = "Left Panel Menu";
        $scope.menuItems = [];
        activate();

        function activate() {
         var moduleId = undefined; 
         var stateName = undefined;

           //This is crude and I do not like it.

           if ($state.params.moduleId != null) {                        
                moduleId = $state.params.moduleId.split(',')[0];
                stateName = $state.params.moduleId.split(',')[1];
            }
            var moduleNum = (moduleId !== null && moduleId !== "" && moduleId !== undefined) ? moduleId : 1;
            $http.get("myJson.js").success(function(data) {
                angular.forEach(data, function(value) {
                    if (value.FK_DbModuleId == moduleNum) {
                        $scope.menuItems.push(value);
                    }
                });
             if(stateName !== undefined) {
                        $state.go(stateName);
                    }
                    return $scope.menuItems;
            });
        }

         $scope.stateGo = function (state, module) {
                var modId = '/' + module.moduleId;
                var stateName = ',' + state.state;
                $location.path(modId + stateName, false); <--- Very crude
            };

    }
]);
```

**My question is 3-fold:**

1. If you go to the plunker example and click on the links, you will see a slight flicker back to the original view from app.run before the intended view shows up (unless the intended & original view are the same). Any suggestions on how to avoid this?
2. I show above two pieces of code that are admittedly ugly but I cannot seem to find a more elegant way, any suggestions?
3. As stated, while this works, warts and all, with ui-router 0.2.0, it does not with 0.2.1, anyone familiar with the newer version that may be able to possibly explain to me why this is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `stateGo` in your `ng-click` inside your HTML markup.

Instead, use the `ui-sref` attribute provided by UI-Router ([doc found here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)). Say you want to load `/users/1` page and you have set the state's name to be `users.profile` with a wildcard `id`. Then you can:

```
<div ui-sref="user.profiles({'id' : user.id})">View my Profile!</div>
```

With `user.id` coming form your scope.

Comment: I tried your suggestion: data-ui-sref="{{viewState.Name}}({'moduleId': menuItem.Fk_ModuleId})" $state.params.moduleId is coming up null.

Comment: What is `menuItem`? Are you doing an `ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems"` somewhere then? Also, in your code above, the `id` is called `moduleId`, not `FK_ModuleId`. Where are you getting that key from?

Comment: Yes, I know it is not null, it is a required property. Can you fork my plunker and show me what you are proposing?

Comment: Can you tell me where the code problem is? Your plunker is too big for me to go through it. What file are you referring to?

Comment: I made an error with my sref, per your proposal, it should have been "data-ui-sref="{{viewState.Name}}({moduleId: viewState.Url})", and the left menu will change, but my view does not.

Comment: Your file `tpl.left1.html` still uses `stateGo` I don't see the implementation of `ui-sref` anywhere

Comment: I updated my plunker with your suggestions to another URL: http://plnkr.co/edit/njlH2hXU3blG9D97vuPw?p=preview Everything you propose works fine with the exception that the flicker still continues.

Answer (score 0):

Click here for **[Plunker Solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/njlH2hXU3blG9D97vuPw?p=preview)**

**The crux of my problem was in the app.run, where my original code:**

```
if (viewState.url != '0') {
    viewStateUrl = "/:moduleId";
}

 var state = {
   "url": viewStateUrl,
   "parent": viewState.parentName,
   "abstract": viewState.isAbstract,
   "views": {}
    };
```

**Should have instead defined viewStateUrl as:**

```
if (viewState.url != '0') {
    viewStateUrl = viewState.name +  "/:moduleId";
}
```

After that it was just a simple matter of redefining my link to:

```
data-ui-sref="{{viewState.name}}({moduleId : viewState.url })"
```

as Kousha had suggested, and updating my controller to only showing the $state.parm for module Id:

```
   function getSideMenuItems() {
     var moduleId = undefined; 
     var stateName = undefined;

    if ($state.params.moduleId != null) { moduleId = $state.params.moduleId;}

    var sideMenuItems = "sideMenuItems";
    var moduleNum = (moduleId !== null && moduleId !== "" && moduleId !== undefined) ? moduleId:1;
                datacontext.getSideMenuItems(sideMenuItems).then(function (data) {
                    angular.forEach(data, function (value) {
                        if (value.fK_DbModuleId == moduleNum) {
                            $scope.menuItems.push(value);
                        }
                    });

                });
                    return $scope.menuItems;
            };
        }
```

**Result:**

1. More elegant
2. No flickering
3. Works in 0.2.1

:)